# How to convert a [x,y] cell point on a grid to a GCPoint & viceversa, Swift 3

Tags: swift, user-interface, matrix, converters, cgpoint

My project is a random maze generation code, and one of the abilities I have is that the user will be able to tap the inner maze walls.

The problem I am having is that since my maze is made using a grid array, each cell in the grid has an `x` and `y` location (ex: `grid[10,1]` is the 10th row and the 1st column). Usually I access these `x` and `y` cell points by iterating through all cells with 2 for loops.

The cell walls each have a property of `up`,`down`,`right`, and `left` which are the four walls of each cell. On these places is where the maze walls are placed.

However since I am trying to code an ability where the user can touch the cell walls, all of those functions and properties are made using `CGPoint` for location.

What I am trying to do is create a function that will be able to take in the `[x,y]` coordinates of a grid cell wall + using the direction of the wall (up, down, left, right) and  and be able to convert that into a specific location.

Something I considered doing was this:

```
func convertGridCellToLocationPoint(x: Int, y: Int) -> (location: CGPoint) {
    //following code
    return (locationX, locationY)
}
```

But I am unsure how to use that function to actually convert the `[x,y]` cell points to an actual `CGPoint` in a variable.

Comment: Isn't each of your cell a `CGRect`?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I think so? Technically yes since each cell being printed on the screen gets it's own location points, but I did not originally create any of the cells using `CGRect` since I made it as a grid with an array.